# In PHP: How do I change lower to upper case in simple string

Tags: php, string

This is very simple but I need  as script where someone from a text field adds a string. The script then counts how many capital A:s there are and how many small a:s there are.

The script should then output number of A:S and a:.s

Thanks very much.

Comment: the question and title are very different.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question. The title is different from the description. If you just want to change from lower to upper there is the PHP function toupper() http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Comment: I'm sorry I was unclear. I want to someone to enter a text from a form field. And the scipt counts how many capital letters and how many upper-cases (A) yjere are

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It made it understand how to solve the whole problem.


I apoplogise for for my newbienss but... whe've alll been there. Thanks again, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Some easy googling would have given you your answer.
This is what the first result gave me, it counts the capitals in a string:

```
function count_capitals($s) {
  return strlen(preg_replace('![^A-Z]+!', '', $s));
}
```

This should be a good start to make your own script which does what you want.